# importing scss in react: Cannot find module scss

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I am trying to import scss and use it in react-css-themr, so when I was not using themr, this importing was working fine: `import "style/Sample.scss"`, but now I need to store it in an object and use it in themr so I am trying to call it like: `import * as SampleTheme from "style/Sample.scss"` & this gives error `Cannot find module`, I am getting this error in terminal itself so build process is not going through. I also tried `const SampleTheme = require("style/Sample.scss")` but this gives me blank object.

Some people are saying its problem with webpack configuration but I am not so sure about it, because in IDE as well when I hover on this I can see the same issue & till that time webpack is not even running, still here is my webpack config for scss:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: false,
            }
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                includePaths: [
                    path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles', 'components'),
                ],
                sourceMap: false
            }
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
                resources: [
                    './node_modules/engage-ui/src/styles/foundation.scss',
                    './node_modules/engage-ui/themes/Delicious/foundation.scss',
                    './node_modules/engage-ui/src/styles/shared.scss',
                    './node_modules/engage-ui/themes/Delicious/shared.scss',
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
},
```

Answer (score -1):

```
module.exports = {
...
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
        }]
    }]
  }
};
```

and **add sass loader**

> yarn add sass-loader node-sass –dev

Comment: I already have all these 3 loaders added in my config file, check my code above in question